# Why is a new HTMLElement() prohibited?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering why `new HTMLElement()` and others (for example `new HTMLDivElement()`) throw illegal constructor error.

I want codes like this:

```js
// create a square with a given length
class Square extends HTMLDivElement {
  constructor(len) {
    super();

    this.style.width = `${len}px`;
    this.style.height = `${len}px`;
    this.style.border = '1px solid black';
  }
}

const square = new Square(5);
document.body.appendChild(square);
```

However, the above code is no less than just a wish, because the above code throws illegal constructor error.

I think there are two workarounds: (1) using $ref (2) using custom element. Please let me show.

(1) Using $ref

```js
class Square {
  constructor(len) {
    const $div = document.createElement('div');

    $div.style.width = `${len}px`;
    $div.style.height = `${len}px`;
    $div.style.border = '1px solid black';

    this.$ref = $div;
  }
}

const square = new Square(5); // returns Square object
document.body.appendChild(square.$ref);
```

This way, I can make a square, but it is inconvenient since I can't access to the div(=$ref) directly. I need to go via 'square' object first. (What I want to say is the difference between `appendChild(square)` and `appendChild(square.$ref)`) Because `new HTMLDivElement()` is not possible, I have no choice but to use an object which acts like a wrapper.

(2) Using (autonomous) custom element -- also uses $ref too.

```js
class Square extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    const $div = document.createElement('div');
    
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild($div);
    this.shadowRoot.$ref = $div;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.$ref.style.width = `${this.dataset.len}px`;
    this.shadowRoot.$ref.style.height = `${this.dataset.len}px`;
    this.shadowRoot.$ref.style.border = '1px solid black';
  }
}

customElements.define('custom-square', Square);

const square = document.createElement('custom-square');
square.setAttribute('data-len', 5);
document.body.appendChild(square);
```

In this case, `new Square(5)` cannot be done because of the illegal constructor error, so I must use `data-len` custom attribute and `connectedCallback()` in order to apply `data-len` to `$ref.style` when `square` is appended to DOM.

Of course I can use both ways, but still I wonder why `new HTMLElement()` is prohibited. Are there any historical reasons for that?

Also, what makes me wonder is that even though `new HTMLElement()` throws illegal constructor error, how `document.createElement()` can make a new instance of HTMLElement (internally)? According to [the first answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220243/instantiating-new-htmlelement-in-typescript), `HTMLElement.constructor()` throws an exception, not creating an object. Then how `HTMLDivElement` is instantiated and returned to me when I call `document.createElement('div')`?

In addition, I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150942/how-to-create-an-instance-of-doms-constructor-functions) that uses `Object.create()` method to create an instance of `HTMLElement`. It works and returns `HTMLElement` instance, but seems the `HTMLElement` instance doesn't work correctly. For example,

```js
const test = Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype, {});

test.textContent = 'test'; // illegal invocation
```

For some reason I can get illegal invocation error. Why is that?

Comment: Yeah, you are probably meant to use `document.createElement` rather than extend the built-in classes.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539002/extending-an-html-element

Comment: I found an answer about this error message https://stackoverflow.com/q/41521812/14032355

Comment: You can use the builtin function `attributeChangedCallback` from custom element to achieve your goal.  After you define a custom element and use document.createElmenet("customElement"), you can set the attribute of the element, and as you set attributeChangedCallback before, it will set the style after you set the attribute.

Comment: Make `Square` to extend `HTMLDivElement`, and then `customElements.define('custom-square', Square, {extends: 'div'});`.

Comment: Because DOM elements are actually more than JS and don't live in the same "realm", because an Element requires an ownerDocument, because ... probably other good reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that this is just how `HTMLDivElement` and `HTMLElement` are defined in the DOM standard at the moment.

To find out more, first take a look at the prototype chain for [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) on MDN:

> EventTarget ← Node ← Element ← HTMLElement

We can find out more information about each of these interfaces in the [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-node). In particular, for `Node` it says:

> Node is an abstract interface that is used by all nodes. You cannot get a direct instance of it.

The spec then says:

> Each node has an associated node document, set upon creation, that is a document.

This explains why we need to use `document.createElement()` to create a HTML element; interfaces with `Node` in their prototype chain must be associated with a document.

The reason why `document.createElement('script')` was chosen over something like `new HTMLSciptElement(document)` is probably because of historical design decisions and consistency with the rest of the DOM which seems to favor factory methods.

There is nothing to stop the authors from making `Node` constructible in the future but the reason this doesn’t exist now is probably because there isn’t demand for it. It’s interesting to note that one step down the prototype chain is [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) which was recently changed to be constructible. It does not have the same document association requirement as `Node`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot. If you don't mind me asking, I would like to ask one more question. Since I'm a beginner, I'm not much aware of some terms like 'interface' which seemingly used in Web IDL. It seems that 'interface' is a thing like 'class', but I wonder what is 'abstract interface' and why Node can't be instantiated directly. Thank you.

Comment: For a definition of interfaces you can go back a step further to the ECMAScript spec, see [Common Iteration Interfaces](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-common-iteration-interfaces) which says _“An interface is a set of property keys whose associated values match a specific specification“_. A data type being ‘abstract’ is a more general term in computing and mathematics but here means that the interface is not a constructor so you can’t make an instance of it.